# Ruby on Rails -- commontator -- use avatar urls instead of paperclip avatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, object-initializers

So I'm using the commontator gem for comments in ruby and I wanna know how I can just use a simple url to display the avatar

My user.avatar is basically a string with a url.
Default:

```
config.user_avatar_proc = lambda { |user, view|
                                     view.commontator_gravatar_image_tag(
                                       user, 1, :s => 60, :d => 'mm') }
```

I have tried:

```
config.user_avatar_proc = lambda { |user, view|
                                     view.image_tag(
                                       user.avatar) }
```

Without any luck

Answer (score 0):

user.avatar is the paperclip object. Inside image tag, use
user.avatar.url(:thumb) (thumb or whatever sizes you have specified)